# Trying to clean up GitLab repository with LFS using git filter-repo, but I increased its size instead of reducing it

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs, git-filter-repo

please help me understand what I did wrong.

I'm following this official GitLab tutorial: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html
I did everything exactly like in the tutorial, I ran Clean Up after 30minutes.
I found somewhere that running housekeeping option might help, so I also ran this one.
My repo size jumped from 6GB to 6,6GB and that's it. I tried to do this twice, as first one didn't work, but it only increased repo size by next 200mb.
I found info that unreferenced LFS files are removed at daily basis, but after 48h no changes.
Do you have any idea what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Maybe a little bit late, but I had the same problem... Try this

Go to Settings -> General -> advanced -> run house keeping